# Can I use Angular 2 without Node, but with Visual Studio?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I work on a project where we use AngularJS 1 with Typescript in Visual Studio. I found [this post](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/10/24/upgrading-apps-to-angular-2-using-ngupgrade.html) which explains how you can use ngUpgrade to slowly move into Angular 2.x+. What I haven't been able to figure out is how to get Angular 2 downloaded/installed and how to include the files into our project.

With AngularJS 1 we download the angular.js file, use a  to include it on the page and away we go.

We don't have node running, since Visual Studio has built-in typescript support and compilation. Can someone help me understand how to download and include Angular 2 along with ngUpdate, include it in my page (which already includes Angular 1), and let Visual Studio do the typescript compiling instead of using Node?

Comment: You should start here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

Comment: Thanks @R.Richards.

For anyone else reading this, you'll want to jump straight to the part that talks about the Upgrade Module:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#upgrading-with-the-upgrade-module

Also here are some other links that explain the process and might be helpful to you:

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/10/24/upgrading-apps-to-angular-2-using-ngupgrade.html

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1157542/Step-by-Step-Setup-Angular-in-Visual-Studio-Update

http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: @R.Richards If you want to add it as an Answer, I'll accept it as the "Correct" one.

Comment: Done. I am glad you found this useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to start with the upgrade guide located at the following link.

[Incrementally upgrade an AngularJS application to Angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html)

Asking to have this sort of thing laid out here on SO is a lot for anyone to do when it is already done for you by the folks at angular.io. The link about is literally a 100 or so pages of information!

Useful bookmark on the page:

[Upgrading with The Upgrade Module](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#upgrading-with-the-upgrade-module)

Good luck to anyone on this journey. Keep an eye out for Angular 4!